# Create Sql Server Reporting Service using subreport to repeat records

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

i am creating a Sql Server Reporting. I want pick one row from one dataset and all details regarding this row under it.
Like Department name Dot-Net is on header and its employee details under it.Then Department PHP and all PHP employee below it.
Here is the sample :-

Department

DotNet

```
       Employee Name                    Age

    Bharat                              25
    Arvind                              28
    Deepak                              30
```

SQL

```
     Employee Name                       AGE
        Aman                               30                                 
        Umesh                              25
```

It is just sample . I want to create same hierarchy for five tables, which linked each other. 
I don't know how to show data like it.
I have used subreports and list also for reporting.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's the question here? What problems are you facing?

Comment: I don't know how to print records like it.

Comment: Is your T-SQL Query completed? Have you tried a matrix in SSRS using groups to display it? (You can use the report templates provided in BIDS to assist you).

Comment: I don't know how to use grouping for it.PLease help me how to use grouping here.Can you send me any link?

Comment: SSRS Tutorials by Microsoft : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb522859%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Dominic, i got idea from here. And Its working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would join the tables together in one dataset using a SQL query.  Then I would define one Table with a Row Group on the Department.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx